# Multiple Firebase projects in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm implementing multiple firebase projects in one app, but I'm having some troubles with the FirebaseOptions.

In the main.dart i have this

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'admin-project',
    options: AdminFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'client-project',
    options: ClientFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

In the firebase_options.dart I have this.

```
class AdminFirebaseOptions {
  static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return web;
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return android;
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for ios - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for macos - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      default:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
        );
    }
  }

  static const FirebaseOptions web = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'mykey',
    appId: 'myappid',
    messagingSenderId: 'mymessaging',
    projectId: 'admin',
    authDomain: 'admin.firebaseapp.com',
    storageBucket: 'admin.appspot.com',
    measurementId: 'G-mymeasurement',
  );

  static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'myapikey',
    appId: 'myapiid',
    messagingSenderId: 'mymessaging',
    projectId: 'admin',
    storageBucket: 'admin.appspot.com',
  );
}

class ClientFirebaseOptions {
  static Future<FirebaseOptions?> get currentPlatform async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return getFirebaseWebOptions();
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return getFirebaseAndroidOptions();
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'AdminFirebaseOptions have not been configured for ios - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'AdminFirebaseOptions have not been configured for macos - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'AdminFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'AdminFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      default:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'AdminFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
        );
    }
  }

  static Future<FirebaseOptions?> getFirebaseWebOptions() async {
    final collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('clients');
    final querySnapshot = await collectionRef
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();

    if (querySnapshot.size == 0) {
      // Handle the case where no document matches the given uid.
      return null;
    } else {
      // Get the first document snapshot in the query snapshot.
      final documentSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs.first;

      // Populate a new instance of FirebaseOptions with data from the Firestore document.
      final FirebaseOptions optionsClientWeb = FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: documentSnapshot.get('apiKeyWeb'),
        authDomain: documentSnapshot.get('authDomain'),
        projectId: documentSnapshot.get('projectId'),
        storageBucket: documentSnapshot.get('storageBucket'),
        messagingSenderId: documentSnapshot.get('messagingSenderId'),
        appId: documentSnapshot.get('appIdWeb'),
        measurementId: documentSnapshot.get('measurementId'),
      );

      return optionsClientWeb;
    }
  }

  static Future<FirebaseOptions?> getFirebaseAndroidOptions() async {
    final collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('clients');
    final querySnapshot = await collectionRef
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();

    if (querySnapshot.size == 0) {
      // Handle the case where no document matches the given uid.
      return null;
    } else {
      // Get the first document snapshot in the query snapshot.
      final documentSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs.first;

      // Populate a new instance of FirebaseOptions with data from the Firestore document.
      final FirebaseOptions optionsClientAndroid = FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: documentSnapshot.get('apiKeyAndroid'),
        appId: documentSnapshot.get('appIdAndroid'),
        projectId: documentSnapshot.get('projectId'),
        storageBucket: documentSnapshot.get('storageBucket'),
        messagingSenderId: documentSnapshot.get('messagingSenderId'),
      );

      return optionsClientAndroid;
    }
  }
}
```

The data is stored in a admin firestore collection that the clients log-in and store the uid.
I'm having trouble with the options in main.dart **The argument type 'Future<FirebaseOptions?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FirebaseOptions?'**

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: You return a `Future` from `currentPlatform`, so you need to `await` on result. However as soon as you need to use Firebase before getting options - that's not gonna work, it's better to store configs somewhere else if you plan to retrieve them for Firebase initialization.